# How do I sum a column of cells by date?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with these data (all of these dates and amounts are **arbitrary**):

```
    A        B
12/1/2015   700
1/7/2016    100
1/13/2016   200
2/5/2016    300
3/19/2016   500
```

and another column with the first date of each month. I'm trying to sum the data by month/year to get something like this:

```
    E         F
12/1/2015    700
1/1/2016     300
2/1/2016     300
3/1/2016     500
```

Entering the dates into the first column of the pseudo pivot table isn't the problem; it's summing the data by date. In column F, I've tried this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(AND(MONTH($A$1:$A$5)=MONTH(E1), YEAR($A$1:$A$5)=YEAR(E1)), $B$1:$B$5)))
```

but this returns all zeros. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As I was building this question, I figured out several ways to achieve this, so I went ahead and shared the information.*

There are several ways to do this. The first is a variation on your original syntax, but using nested [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) statements instead of `IF` and `AND`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(MONTH($A$1:$A$5)=MONTH(E1), IF(YEAR($A$1:$A$5)=YEAR(E1), $B$1:$B$5))))
```

The second uses the [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function. This method will return a `#N/A` error if `FILTER` doesn't find any matches for the conditions. `FILTER` takes each condition as a separate argument:

```
=SUM(FILTER($B$1:$B$5, MONTH($A$1:$A$5)=MONTH(E1), YEAR($A$1:$A$5)=YEAR(E1)))
```

The third uses [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) and [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en):

```
=INDEX(SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=MONTH(E2))*(YEAR($A$2:$A$6)=YEAR(E2))*$B$2:$B$6), 1)
```

In each of these examples, I assumed that the data were in columns A and B, the "pivot table" dates were in column E, and the aggregated data are placed in column F.

There might be a way to do this with the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function that provides an interface to the Google Visualization API Query Language, but I'm not sure. I don't know if such a query would dynamically update, either.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution with query, you can try:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({text(A1:A, "mm/yy"), B1:B}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) where not(Col1) contains '99' group by Col1 "))
```

Comment: Can you explain this query a little? Specifically, I'm unsure what `contains '99'` is used for, since according to the documentation, `contains` is used for substring matches.

Comment: The text function converts col A to a 'mm/yy' format. If there are empty cells in col A they will be converted to 12/99 by using where not(Col1) contains '99' we are excluding those rows.